# partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to do a series expansion of this forumla
$$z = \sqrt{\frac{x+1}{y+1}}.$$

I need to get Zx Zxx and so on. but I really dont know where to start with this this.

just a push in the right direction should be enough.

Comment: Pretend that y is just a constant, and differentiate like you would normally do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to differentiate already, remember that partial differentiation with respect to a certain independent variable treats the other independent variables as constants.

To use $(x+y)^2$ as an example, $\partial_x (x+y)^2$ is just $2(x+y)$ (chain rule). Now try this operation on your function.